# Realtime works, overview doesn't

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

To check if my google analytics code worked, I checked the realtime function on the analytics page. However, in the overview by hour/day/week/month it doesn't show any visitors.

Inserted the code more than a week ago, so 24h/48h have already passed by. I did have the Insights plugin on wordpress running for analytics but have deactivated that plugin.

Does anyone heard of this before or maybe experienced this himself and know the solution to this? I honestly have no idea what I might be doing wrong.

Edit: In the top-right corner (on the audience overview page), when I change *the period* from 'Last week' to 'Last month', it DOES show some visitors. However, been visiting the site a couple of times yesterday/today on different devices and weekly still doesn't show anything..

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out. You can choose between 'Last month' or 'Last 30 days'. There is, of course, a clear difference between these two. 'Last month' will show the visitors from February, the month before we're in right now.(March) 'Last 30 days' will show the last 30 days, also in the month we're in right now.

Dumb me..